# Request.form returns value with comma

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

When I run this code:

```
string MySQL = "Select * From RegisterDatabase Where uName  = '" + Request.Form["username"] +"'";
```

It didn't work for me, so I tried to see what the problem was and it turns out there's a comma in MySQL.

```
Select * From RegisterDatabase Where uName  = 'Test,'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use following

Request.Form["username"].ToString().Replace(',',' ').Trim();

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! =)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is prone to [SQL Injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

You want to parameterized query like this -

```
string query = "Select * From RegisterDatabase Where uName = @username";

// Remove "," from username
string username = Request.Form["username"].ToString().Replace(",", "");

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
```

Or some use `?username` instead of `@username`.